# Rails build_asset in create action for accepts_nested_attributes_for relationship not preserving relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a `Listings` model which `accepts_nested_attributes_for` an `Asset` model. On my site users are allowed to upload multiple photos per listing but each listing itself only has one asset:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :asset, inverse_of: :listing
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :asset, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and then the asset has the multiple attached files

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing, inverse_of: :asset
  has_attached_file :photo1
  has_attached_file :photo2
  has_attached_file :photo3
  validates :listing_id, presence: true
end
```

(like I said i'm using paperclip so i have all the necessary validations etc I just took them out to make this shorter and only show what's necessary)

In my `ListingsController` the `new` action is:

```
def new
    @listing = Listing.new
    @listing.build_asset
 end
```

and this is the `create` action:

```
def create
   @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
   @listing.user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])
   respond_to do |format|
    if @listing.save
     format.html { redirect_to user_listing_path(@listing.user, @listing), notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
     format.js {}
    else
      @listing.build_asset
      format.html { render :new}
      format.js {}
     end
    end
  end
```

Now, when I create a listing, whether it comes from the `new` or 'create' action, the photos don't get saved and I get the error on my form `Asset listing can't be blank`. Now I know `@listing.build_asset` has to be working because the actual file upload fields show up, but for whatever reason it isn't connecting that asset with that listing.

My form view is pretty long so I'll abbreviate it:

````
<%= javascript_include_tag "listing/global_listing_form.js" %>
<div class="row">```
<%= form_for [current_user, @listing], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
 <% if @listing.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  Please correct the following <%= pluralize(@listing.errors.count, "error") %>:
   <ul>
    <% @listing.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
  </div>
 <% end %>

<div id="listing-form-product-info">
<%= render 'assets/upload_photos', f: f %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
</div> <!-- end listing-form-product-info   -->
</div>
````

and the `render 'assets/upload_photos', f: f` renders this:

```
<div id="uploads_container">
<br>
  <h3 class="button">The first photo will be your display photo</h3>
    <br>
    <%= f.fields_for :asset do |asset_photo| %>
      <%= asset_photo.file_field :photo1, class: "upload-field" %>
      <%= asset_photo.file_field :photo2, class: "upload-field" %>
      <%= asset_photo.file_field :photo3, class: "upload-field" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

So as I said, the problem is that the asset file fields show up, but when the form is actually submitted there is no relationship between that built asset and the listing it was created for.

Here's my `listing_params` method as requested:

```
def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:user_id, :brand_id, :category_id, :size_id, :gender_id, :title, :description, :original_price, :price, :condition,:tag_list, asset_attributes: [:id, :photo1, :photo2, :photo3])
    end
```

Here are the params from a listing I just tried creating:

```
Parameters: {
"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"3YjdJZWfClaUvTCW7MVdQ1hTBLPMow8QISBBQ1daI70=",
 "listing"=>{
"gender_id"=>"1", 
"category_id"=>"11", 
"asset_attributes"=>{
"photo1"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f535cccdf10 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140529-5-ska7i8>, 
@original_filename="tumblr_mkk8iwuXCD1r05jkho1_1280.jpg", 
@content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"listing[asset_attributes][photo1]\"; 
filename=\"tumblr_mkk8iwuXCD1r05jkho1_1280.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,

"photo2"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f535cccddd0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140529-5-1ospj13>,
@original_filename="rsaah300_menthe.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"listing[asset_attributes][photo2]\"; filename=\"rsaah300_menthe.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,

"photo3"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f535cccdc18 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140529-5-edwbz1>, @original_filename="9200703.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"listing[asset_attributes][photo3]\"; 
filename=\"9200703.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
"title"=>"Mint Disco Pants", 
"brand_id"=>"1", 
"original_price"=>"80", 
"price"=>"47", 
"description"=>"American Apparel Mint High-waist disco pants\r\nBrand New, Never worn\r\n\r\nDescription from American Apparel site:\r\nForm-fitting, high-waist stretch pants made from a heavyweight Nylon/Elastane blend that creates a flattering slimming effect.\r\n\r\n• Nylon Spandex (90% Nylon / 10% Elastane) construction \r\n• Medium is approximately 30” (76.2cm) in total length \r\n• Metal zipper and button closure \r\n• Dual back pockets \r\n• Form-fitting \r\n• When in doubt on sizing, order down\r\n",
 "size_id"=>"30", 
"condition"=>"New without tags", 
"tag_list"=>"high waisted, disco pants, disco"}, 
"commit"=>"Create Listing", 
"user_id"=>"lexy"}
```

also, perhaps worth noting!
When I create a listing without uploading any photos, the listing is created. When I then go to edit the listing and add photos, the photos work and it recognizes that those photos belong to *that* listing. Which doesn't make sense since they are using the exact same form!

Comment: can you show your listing_params method

Comment: @SahilGrover just added it! thanks for taking a look.

Comment: everything seems prettty fine. Can you add more of your params/logs that you get on console..., @also are you sure User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])is returning you a user and not nil

Comment: i set user_id to return the username instead in order to have the url including the username instead of an id number. and yes hold on a second i'll add it

Comment: @SahilGrover okay, posted my params. the asset attributes clearly belong to the listing, but perhaps not the asset itself? should i be passing in the asset's id in a `hidden_field` on the asset building form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by removing the listing_id validation on the asset model.